# Flash player advert that incorporates 3d type effect on screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, flash, 3d

I saw an advert recently that had this awesome feature that I have never seen before, the ad is from www.123.ie and its the one featuring the wellingtons and the rain.  I cant find this ad any more as the 3d effect version was used exclusively on player.utv.ie and has been decommisioned now.  you can still see the regular version on youtube.  I have attached a screenshot from the 3d effect version and I am wondering how they managed to pull off this cool effect?  The player used is flash player and the site is fairly standard in the background, they must have used extra code in the standard html too to allow the water to fall down the screen.  Anyone with any ideas would be great.

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Do you have the code of the page? What have you tried so far?

Comment: No, I just got the screenshot recently, I had a hard time tracking it down!  The ad is slightly different for the 3d splash scene from the side, I presume their is a transluscent animation on the main page that kicks in with the video but I could be wrong.

Comment: The ad is over so cant get the page code, they change their 5 adverts everyday anyway.

Comment: I'm sorry shane, but this type of question is not suitable for StackOverflow. This website is for when you're already developing something, and need help with a specific coding issue

Comment: Ok, ill come back once I have something up and ready.